# How to fix backup & migrate End of script output before headers: index.php error

Tags: backups

I am getting the following errors in the Apache log when I run backup (entire site) on my local computer using Acquia Dev Desktop.

> [Thu Oct 15 18:11:47.700156 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2912:tid 908]
>   [client 127.0.0.1:60171] mod_fcgid: read timeout from pipe, referer:
>   http://openoutreach-7-x-1-19.dd:8083/admin/config/system/backup_migrate/export/advanced
>   [Thu Oct 15 18:11:47.700156 2015] [core:error] [pid 2912:tid 908]
>   [client 127.0.0.1:60171] End of script output before headers:
>   index.php, referer:
>   http://openoutreach-7-x-1-19.dd:8083/admin/config/system/backup_migrate/export/advanced
>   [Thu Oct 15 18:11:57.987744 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2912:tid 324]
>   mod_fcgid: process 9460 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Those are PHP/server errors.